# AEM Form dialog without REST submission endpoint

Tags: forms, aem

We need to submit AEM 6.0 form to external URL and found the [Adobe instruction](https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6/configuring-submit-actions.html#Post%20submitted%20data%20to%20a%20resource%20or%20external%20rest%20end%20point) with dialog https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6/configuring-submit-actions/_jcr_content/main-pars/image_1.img.png/d2.PNG but strangely our dialog does not have field to 'Enable POST request' or 'URL for POST request' [image]

Can someone help advising what we need to do to get these fields displayed ?

Comment: Can you use a custom servlet that handles your form-submit action or do you need to define only through the dialog? I have a solution if you can use custom servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe added this functionality in the add-on package (FP1). Just download and install ADOBE FORMS 6.0 FP1 package from the official site or via Package Share, and both fields 'Enable POST request' and 'URL for POST request' will appear.